# Why setWifiEnabaled() does not work when airplanemode is on?

Tags: android

I've used the following method to enable and disable wifi in android 9. When airplane mode is on it doesn't work:

```
    public static void setWifi(boolean enable , Context context){
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(enable);
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?

Comment: No, I didn't find any solution